# Express $(a*b)^{-1}$ in terms of $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Express $(a*b)^{-1}$ in terms of $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$.

a and b are elements of a group.
* is the operation.

I know $(a*b)^{-1}$ is not equal to $a^{-1}$ * $b^{-1}$.

I also understand that $b$ * $b^{-1}$ = e, were e is the identity element.

What I don't understand is what other ways I can combine $(a*b)^{-1}$

Something I tried.

$(a*b)^{-1}$ *$(a *b)$ = $e$

$(a*b)^{-1}$ *$(a *b)$ *$b^{-1}$ = $b^{-1}$

$(a*b)^{-1}$ * $a$ * ($b$ * $b^{-1}$) = $b^{-1}$

$(a*b)^{-1}$ * $a$  =  $b^{-1}$

Is this on the right path?

Comment: What $a,b,*$ are?

Comment: Are $a,b$ elements of a group $G$ with binary operation $*$?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  What guesses do you have?  Could you figure this out if $a,b$ were real numbers?  What if they were matrices?

Comment: The problem doesn't say. I believe a and b are elements of a group say G. * is the operation.

Answer (score 1):

What's the property of $b^{-1}$? That $b*b^{-1}=e$ (the neutral element). Then you can also say that
$$
a*(b*b^{-1})=a*e=a
$$
or, by associativity, that
$$
(a*b)*b^{-1}=a
$$
Now you need to “throw away” $a$. How can you do it? With the same idea.

Comment: Multiple both sides by $a^{-1}$.

Comment: @StevenLynn You have to be careful with the side you multiply on. But your aim is to have $(a*b)$ with some element to its right.

Comment: Everything should be on the left side shouldn't it?

Comment: @StevenLynn Er, no: $((a*b)*b^{-1})*a^{-1}=\dots$. When I teach this I usually use the example of socks and shoes: you wear first socks then shoes; when you go to bed, you first kick off the shoes, then the socks.

Comment: $e$ correct? So I want to write it as ($($a$ *$b$)^{-1}$*(($a$ *$b$)*$b^{-1}$))?

Comment: @StevenLynn You're going the wrong direction. Since $((a*b)*b^{-1})*a^{-1}=e$, you can shift parentheses by associativity and get $(a*b)*(b^{-1}*a^{-1})=e$. What's the definition of inverse?

Answer (score 0):

Check the naive guess $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$ is false in general. (Why guess that? What kind of group and group elements do you think we should choose for a counterexample?) What other way is there to combine the two terms $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ with multiplication in a group? Now check that the new expression you get *does* satisfy the property of being $ab$'s inverse.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** the answer is not $a^{-1}*b^{-1}$, though it is tempting to think so

Comment: Yeah I got that. That is why I posted the question.

Comment: What else could it be, then?  Also, for future reference, you should put what you've tried along with the question rather than simply give the question without any context

Comment: So, for example, "I know that the answer isn't $a^{-1}*b^{-1}$" would be a helpful piece of information for the answerer

Comment: Fair enough. I will keep this in mind for my next question.

Answer (score 0):

Allright, I have no idea about abstract mathematics, but I'll give it a shot. Forgive me if I do something ignorant.

Assumption 1: the operation $*$ is associative

Assumption 2: $a*e = a $

Given: $b * b^{−1} = e $

It's easily proven that $b^{−1} * b = e $

Let's say: $ a * b = c $

Then

$c * c^{−1} = e $

$(a*b) * c^{−1} = e $

$a^{−1} * (a*b) * c^{−1} = a^{−1} $

$b * c^{−1} = a^{−1} $

$b^{−1} * b * c^{−1} = b^{−1} * a^{−1} $

$c^{−1} = b^{−1} * a^{−1} $

However, it was claimed that

$(a*b)^{−1}$ is not $a^{−1} * b^{−1} $

However, it was never said that $a^{−1} * b^{−1}$ equals $b^{−1} * a^{−1} $

I haven't seen any indication that $ a*b = b*a $